# Is BlockChain wallet payment API support to send amount from Marchent wallet to external bitcoin wallet address?

Tags: php, wallet, blockchain.info-api

I'm facing a issue  with blockchain bitcoin wallet payment API (mentioned below).

```
http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/payment?password=$main_password&second_password=$second_password&to=$address&amount=$amount&from=$from&fee=$fee
```

**this above API giving below error, when I'm trying to send amount from one merchant wallet to some other **external wallet**.**  (send-funds-externally)

```
Array
(
    [error] => Error signing and pushing transaction
)
```

Can someone please guide me , Is any blockchain api support to send amount externally?

---

==>>**What I have done till now**

I have successfully integrated blockchain node in my server. and I have created wallet in blockchain . and created many merchant wallet through blockchian wallet API . and I have sent amount from one merchant wallet to another merchant wallet through above mentioned api(blockchain paymet API) . all thing is working fine till now.

---

Only my last test is pending. I want to send amount/bitcoin from merchant wallet(related with blockchain) to external wallet address. **I have external wallet address which I created in other website . I want to send amount through API from merchant address to another External wallet address**. can someone guide me how can I send.

---

Comment: According [this comment](https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3/issues/128#issuecomment-366414043) on GitHub issues, one of the cases that return this error is when you're sending a very small amount (few hundred sats). Is this your case? Also what is the value of `$fee`? I see some arbirtary minimal value [here](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api) as well.